# Would "mid-to-late" and "low-to-mid" hyphenated as compound modifiers?

Tags: punctuation

Would "mid-to-late" and "low-to-mid" be hyphenated as compound modifiers?

Examples:

Temperatures are expected to be in the low-to-mid 60s.

Joe, I think, is in his mid-to-late 80s.

He was in his middle-to-late 40s.

She was in her middle-to-upper 60s.

Temperatures are expected to be in the lower-to-middle 70s.

Are all correct?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

Good question.

It depends on how you see the things you're describing in your mind.

There are subtle differences that variations in the punctuation can convey - for instance:

> in her middle-to-upper-60s

treats the whole phrase as a compound noun.
It's like saying 'She was in her kitchen'.

> in her middle- to upper-60s

puts the focus on both ends of the stated range.

> in her middle-to-upper 60s

treats 'middle-to-upper' as a compound adjective.
It's like saying 'She was in her warm kitchen'.

> in her middle to upper 60s

has the potential to confuse the reader, who might first read 'she was in her middle' as a complete phrase before getting the intended sense.

So, yes, in short, your examples are correct grammatically - however, do they accurately convey your meaning? Only you can say.